# Android authentication and sessions

Tags: android, session, authentication

How do I keep users logged in after authentication in Android apps? I did some reading, and frankly am a little inexperienced regarding sessions, but it looks like after the user submits their credentials to the server and is authenticated, the server then sends back a session ID. This session ID I presume is stored somewhere on the user's android device.

Should I use sharedPreferences, the sqlite db, or local storage to save the session id? I read that shared preferences is somewhat insecure, whereas the sqlite db or local storage would be restricted only to a single app.

Also, should I make an HTTP request to the server to send/receive this info, or can it be done through socket connections. Ultimately I want to make a multiplayer game that will use sockets, though I suppose certain features like logging in don't necessarily have to be through a socket, not sure if there's a standard or usual way that game developers usually do this.

Answer (score 0):

> should I make an HTTP request to the server to send/receive this info

I don't think you just want to send your authentication over HTTP. Potentially people could intercept your packages and read back data in plain text. If you have an API on a server which your android application authenticates with, I would recommend using HTTPS to communicate.

> Should I use sharedPreferences, the sqlite db, or local storage to save the session id?

I myself use sharedPreferences in 'MODE_PRIVATE' to store the ID. There are different modes in which you can create a sharedPreferences file. Private mode means it can only be accessed by your application or applications with the same user ID. All the modes are are explained here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29

If you want to store passwords and users on your android device I would suggest using a database. Make sure you secure your passwords with 'salt and pepper':

http://barkingiguana.com/2009/08/03/securing-passwords-with-salt-pepper-and-rainbows/

> not sure if there's a standard or usual way that game developers usually do this

Can't help you with this question, but I think if you do some research you'll be able to figure it out ;).

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response. HTTPS would make more sense being that it's encrypted, I guess my question was more should I send the users login info and respond with a session id through a socket or https. I suppose it would work with a socket so long as its a secure socket connection.